# Filtering data on 2 fields using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following sample data :-

```
ID  PET_TYPE  REF
101 Dog       1
102 Cat       7
103 Gerbil    2
104 Cat       9
105 Mouse     5
106 Cat       1
107 Rabbit    2
```

Using Oracle, is it possible to return all pet types, but only type Cat when the Ref is 9. So the expected output would be :-

```
ID  PET_TYPE  REF
101 Dog       1
103 Gerbil    2
104 Cat       9
105 Mouse     5
107 Rabbit    2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where pet_type <> 'Cat' 
or ref = 9
```

Comment: So, this will work with a pet_type of Dog, and a Ref of 9?